# Retrieve index of listitem when button clicked within listitem

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-listview

I have a `CustomListView`, where each `ListItem` contains a `Button'. When  a certain`Button` is clicked, I want a particular task to be performed.

Problem: How to get index of `ListItem` of `Button` clicked?

Here is code snippet:

```
public View getView(final int position,View view, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_single, null, true);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
txtTitle.setText(title.get(position));


button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Here I want to get the id of the list item clicked.
    try {
        new loadaa().execute().get(7000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    if (good){

    }else{

    }
}
}); 



return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `position` from the parameter of the `getView`. Actually `position` is the index of the `ListItem`.

**sample:**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    //Here I want to get the id of the list item clicked.
    int index = position; //the index of the listItem.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to set position to button tag and get this tag value on click of button as follow.


        button.setTag(position);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Here I want to get the id of the list item clicked.
            int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());

            try {
                new loadaa().execute().get(7000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (good){

            }else{

            }
            }
        });
```